# Convert byte array of signed ints to file - Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have message from server in following format

```
result = "123,-23,12,...,54,-53"
```

That message represents array byte of image. How can I convert this to actual image?

I converted this *result* to array of ints and tried with:

```
File.open( 'imageX.png', 'wb' ) do |output|
  splited.each do | byte |
      output.print byte
  end
end
```

But image is not recognizable. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect you'll want to try something like:

```
File.write("imageX.png", result.split(',').map(&:to_i).pack('C*'))
```

This converts it to bytes then "packs" each one as a character (one byte).

I hope that helps.

Cheers!

Comment: That's exactly what I needed! Cheers!